# Add new column to the whole database table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, alter-table

I have a database (aca) which I need to add a new column to all tables in using one sql query.

I used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706740/adding-column-to-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-unknown-table-names), but it gives me error when applying the sql query.

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',
table_schema,
'.',
table_name,
' ADD COLUMN parent default 0;') AS ddl
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/alter_table.sql'
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'aca' 
AND table_type = 'base table';

\. /tmp/alter_table.sql
```

this error:

> 1 - Can't create/write to file '\tmp\alter_table.sql' (Errcode: 2 - No
>   such file or directory)

Please, any ideas?

Comment: why you wan't to Take The Output IN .SQL File as you are Getting It Dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Remove The Input File And Run Below Query

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',
table_schema,
'.',
table_name,
' ADD COLUMN parent default 0;') AS ddl

FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'aca' 
AND table_type = 'base table';
```

Comment: it gives me a ddl table which has length the same of the number of the tables,

Comment: with each row 
ddl
ALTER TABLE aca.a1a ADD COLUMN parent INTEGER  def..

Comment: it doesn't add on the aca tables actually!